# Revoking sharing URL for file

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to revoke the sharing URL for a file with the Google Drive API after it has been created? I checked the docs but can't see anything relevant. I know it's possible with the DropBox and OneDrive APIs but it doesn't look like it can be done with Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `delete` operation in Google Drive API to revoke/delete access to a file.

HTTP Request should look like this:
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions/permissionId

You can explore the references below for further details about Google Drive API and DELETE operation.

[Share files, folders and drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing#revoke_access_to_a_file_or_folder)

[Permissions: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/delete)